# Can you find the mistake in my custom evaluation metric? XGBOOST R

Tags: r, xgboost

I am trying to add a custom evaluation metric in xgboost in R. In this example the predictions on the testing data are 0.4399617 and 0.2455548. The evaluation metric should say 0.3299713 at iteration 100, but it says 0 through all iterations. Here is my code. What am I missing?

```
require(xgboost)
set.seed(1)

training_vectors<-structure(c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                              1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
                              0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.941638125728341, 1.15364696297532, 
                              0.558399566424809, 0.559068309566054, 1.34949191060958, 0.614667592104398, 
                              0.207457370529451, 1.66408696198076, 0.76941954573777, -1.85691525645726, 
                              -0.0613798089093204, 0.20816125741963, -0.436302839464195, 0.574420472319906, 
                              1.24323759174665, -0.467671854259046, 0.585910761696343, 0.423800826967858, 
                              0.945893018087821, 0.634033886774145, -0.170806014074692, 1.20924568989354, 
                              -0.668327426122953, 1.89404791341356, 0.709921569900634, 1.4457264865345, 
                              1.22925123638156, -2.521332087981, 0.76941954573777, -0.267363051433809, 
                              -1.7861474451685, 0.869918459564304, 0.600571391571742, 1.13777309775596, 
                              0.313749021477565, 0.111930375282131, 0.295723261240941, -2.04696858752227, 
                              -0.97008985024718, 0.873483392785015, -1.0981420685219, 1.00467719588919, 
                              0.740785038669935, -0.677232827891266, -0.0766134135029085, -1.08143136489723, 
                              0.216661556244158, -1.1272647763345, -1.61180487843188, -1.63155599746285, 
                              2.15000886809406, 2.53192103573109, 0.70440536695558, 0.946339932753538, 
                              0.943524028634784, 0.530787783016417, -0.102653872127614, 0.613598009661027, 
                              0.583935505954246, -1.51512017663048, -0.0706365387617147, 0.0125717436939713, 
                              -0.352542515747031, 0.395209376148268, 0.517331305821383, -0.394815389936023, 
                              1.10604808665121, 0.203372942327374, -0.0224412487659761, 0.295119053511649, 
                              -0.210267894496878, -0.140104931734263, -0.567507664011455, 2.55041654544799, 
                              0.106082577868771, 0.575002046761972, 1.05666473460522, -1.2591919695921, 
                              0.583935505954246, -0.333784770325339, -0.932439256507077, 0.943415608073274, 
                              1.11486885051983, 0.911690809656619, 1.01832626935543, -0.269520909228016, 
                              0.524767862503835, -2.57382748554509, -0.854732466657237, 0.162199692992326, 
                              -0.897155532683592, 0.847232738311629, 1.39468973142335, -0.538626895200607, 
                              -0.0526162811083247, -0.949650083397134, 0.123673629179791, -0.964074555799597, 
                              -0.466180877467377, -0.889901074779966, -0.877961787746227, -0.440551755277531, 
                              -0.437089625668648, 0.145465596919057, 1.97946702545303, 0.705881542891751, 
                              -0.652983064702968, -1.29750592515877, -0.666105460592316, 0.695743768828895, 
                              1.31499420613652, -0.489916890095383, 0.746697613155754, -1.80939055796183, 
                              -0.683018482311327, -0.689851440901128, 0.639573132787043, -0.501302309205543, 
                              -1.37282606099636, 0.577185268899497, 1.24513622074992, 0.728305296064452, 
                              -0.860670337014914, 1.13993892317613, -0.0055917224731583, -0.772799096757393, 
                              0.152452209168004, -0.333258731135924, -0.666105460592316, 0.34332315765547, 
                              -1.41585084443192, -0.585375321510597, -0.453792414724353, 1.0884216380393, 
                              0.011045277153211, -0.447629850436624, 0.879135472478845, 0.659622183932429, 
                              0.362355620754987, -2.01778316638862, 1.02943598434488, -2.26969617624586, 
                              -0.589076976166479, 1.14150317555875, -0.0163468910582442, 0.559033964119561, 
                              -3.30870348382885, 0.599666170996592, -1.64650347971611, -0.480310994666598
), .Dim = c(50L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c(1:50), c("feature_1", "feature_2", 
                                                  "feature_3", "feature_4")))
testing_vectors<-structure(c(1, 1, 1.78188666352518, 0.501744180397169, 1.948022033796133, 
                             0.565917845278659, -1.208314471487369, -0.624564113268186), .Dim = c(2L, 
                                                                                                  4L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2"), c("feature_1", "feature_2", 
                                                                                                                                           "feature_3", "feature_4")))
training_vectors<-xgb.DMatrix(data=as.matrix(training_vectors),label=as.matrix(c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
                                                                                 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
                                                                                 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                 0L, 1L, 1L)))
testing_vectors<-xgb.DMatrix(data=as.matrix(testing_vectors))
watchlist <- list(test=testing_vectors)
my_metric <- function(preds,testing_vectors){
  g<-c(0.75,1.5)
  c<-ifelse(preds-0.05<0.20,0,preds)
  d<-c*g
  result_matrix<-sum(d)
  return(list(metric = "result", value = result_matrix))
}   
trained_models<-xgb.train(data=training_vectors,gamma=0,nrounds=100,max_depth=2,objective="binary:logistic", verbose = 0,feval=my_metric,watchlist = watchlist)
print(predict(trained_models,testing_vectors))
print(trained_models$evaluation_log$test_result)
```

Comment: Are you sure about the final value of the evaluation metric? I am getting something totally different if I set the objective of the evaluation as ```MAXIMIZE=TRUE```. The predictions have been same though.

Comment: what are you getting as the final value of the evaluation metric instead? Adding Maximize = TRUE is not changing anything for me. If the predictions at iteration 100 are 0.4399617 and 0.2455548 all the evaluation metric does is take each value and subtract  0.05, anything less than 0.2 is then set to zero. This vector c is then multiplied by vector g. the sum of that vector should be the result of the evaluation metric ( 0.4399617 *  0.75 + 0.0000000 * 1.5) =  0.3299713. R just gives me zero though.

Comment: I did it differently a bit, adding the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One empty list can be created to store the value of every evaluation metric. And then we can run a loop.

```
eval_metric <- c()

for (i in 1:100) {
  
  trained_models<-xgb.train(data=training_vectors,gamma=0,nrounds=i,max_depth=2,objective="binary:logistic", verbose = 0,feval=my_metric,watchlist = watchlist)
  eval_metric[i] <- my_metric(predict(trained_models,testing_vectors), testing_vectors)$value
}
```

The output:

```
eval_metric

  [1] 1.0833762 1.0332087 1.0702217 1.1165583 0.9980249 1.0447095 0.9964721 0.9674231 0.8648293
 [10] 0.9044608 0.8724537 0.9304222 0.8491665 0.8829176 0.9304336 0.9221882 0.8533177 0.8376518
 [19] 0.7965470 0.8284276 0.8067912 0.7947449 0.7577542 0.7864774 0.7560513 0.7355429 0.7609600
 [28] 0.7640666 0.7101464 0.7291165 0.7655773 0.7347603 0.6886943 0.7110074 0.6942958 0.6838692
 [37] 0.2975801 0.3121724 0.6874055 0.3178953 0.3018035 0.3133702 0.6857661 0.6927544 0.3043382
 [46] 0.2982567 0.2908952 0.2772635 0.2722214 0.2677541 0.2610758 0.2715461 0.2818424 0.3041806
 [55] 0.3227641 0.3138340 0.3105319 0.3045225 0.3009517 0.3114915 0.3061301 0.3169128 0.3118879
 [64] 0.3083425 0.3185155 0.3115889 0.3202170 0.3141242 0.3115893 0.3265834 0.3178155 0.3211948
 [73] 0.3145838 0.3232811 0.3168709 0.3215020 0.3140709 0.3214312 0.3146561 0.3219147 0.3156422
 [82] 0.3099746 0.3176437 0.3261342 0.3212111 0.3146619 0.3215416 0.3296011 0.3362954 0.3328568
 [91] 0.3266897 0.3216920 0.3297096 0.3246411 0.3192709 0.3235182 0.6988236 0.3270507 0.7030137
[100] 0.3299713
```

And the 100th value is 0.3299713.

Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. While this does work it is computationally intensive, dramatically increasing training times.  Isn't the watchlist parameter in xgb.train supposed to monitor the evaluation metric, so xgb.train only has to be run once? Making an additional loop seems unnecessary. If I run print(trained_models$evaluation_log$test_result) in my example it gives a vector just like your for loop, it's just not calculating the evaluation metric properly. Do I have to add something to the watchlist? Thank you for your help.